# Method Reference of Java

Tags: java

According to [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), the `String::compareToIgnoreCase` is also a valid method reference, my question is that `compareToIgnoreCase` is not a static method, in other words, `compareToIgnoreCase` must be attached to a specific `String` instance. So how does JDK know which instance of `String` I refer when I use `String::compareToIgnoreCase` ?

Comment: When you call it you have to supply the strings.

Comment: That same documentation page you linked explains this. See the "Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example using `toUpperCase` which is also an instance method.

It works in this case because the Stream item that is being handled is of the same type as the class of the method being invoked.  So the item actually invokes the method directly.

So for

```
Stream.of("abcde").map(String::toUpperCase).forEach(System.out::println);
```

the `String::toUpperCase` call will be the same as `"abcde".toUpperCase()`

If you did something like this:

```
Stream.of("abcde").map(OtherClass::toUpperCase).forEach(System.out::println);
```

"abcde" is not a type of `OtherClass` so the `OtherClass` would need to look like the following for the stream to work.

```
class OtherClass {
    public static String toUpperCase(String s) {
       return s.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String::compareToIgnoreCase` is not used such as `str1.compareToIgnoreCase(str2)` would be.
It actually is used as a comparator.
E.g. you could compare it to

```
Arrays.sort(someIntegerArray, Collections.reverseOrder())
```

but in this case it would be

```
Arrays.sort(someStringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is like there is an additional parameter, the actual instance, involved.

Example for `String::compareToIgnoreCase`:

```
ToIntBiFunction<String, String> func = String::compareToIgnoreCase;
int result = func.applyAsInt("ab", "cd");    // some negative number expected
```

We get a `ToIntBiFunction` - a two parameter function returning `int` - since the result is an `int`, the first parameter correspond to `this` of `compareToIgnoreCase` and the second function parameter is the parameter passed to `compareToIgnoreCase`.

---

maybe a bit easier:

```
ToIntFunction<String> f = String::length;  // function accepting String, returning int
int length = f.applyAsInt("abc");          // 3
```

`length` does not accept any parameter, but the first argument of the function is used as the instance `length` is called on

---

The examples above are very abstract, just to show the types involved. The functions are mostly used directly in some method call, no need to use an intermediate variable